# Cannot get result when passing php variable to mysql query

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a part of a file name as a parameter in the my sql query in php. My file name is in the form 
db_feature_T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.txt
from which I want the part except the db_feature and .txt i.e.
T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521

I want the img_id from the database whose img_path=dressimages/T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.jpg

My code is as follows.I was able to seperate the file name but I cannot get any result from the database.

```
            <?php
    include('db.php');

    if ($handle = opendir('C:\Users\adithi.a\Desktop\db_features')) {



        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            $entry=substr($entry,11,-4); //this seperates the file name db_feature_T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.txt to T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521



            $image_path='dressimages/'.$entry.'.jpg';//I want to pass the img_path as it is saved in the database in the form of dressimages/T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.jpg


         $result=  mysql_query("select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='$image_path'") or die("Sorry");
          echo $result;//I dont get anything as output. 
        }

    }

        closedir($handle);
    ?>
```

I went to an infinite loop when executing the code above so i tried:

```
    $image_path='dressimages/'.$entry.'.jpg';//I want to pass the img_path as it is saved in the database in the form of dressimages/T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.jpg

        $sql = "select img_id from tbl_image where img_path=".$image_path;
     echo $sql . '<br />';
        $result=mysql_query("$sql");

       }

            while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                  {

                   echo $data["img_id"];
                   }
```

and Now i get the error mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\FashionBonanza\Readfile.php on line 34

Any help

Comment: Try doing this.. `$result=  mysql_query("select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='" . $image_path . "'") or die("Sorry");` Just let me know what happens..

Comment: or better yet, add `or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: @HirenPandya : That's not a problem.

Comment: didn't work the page keeps on loading as it went to some infinite loop

Comment: u have to do echo query and check it in database

Comment: @nl-x - I think he's trying to iterate through a file and then get id of image (from database)

Comment: @user1583647 - How does the C:\Users\adithi.a\Desktop\db_features look like? Please give a few rows example.

Comment: by the way, just before doing `mysql_query()` first do: `$image_path = mysql_real_escape_string($image_path);` to escape any bad characters such as `'` that will break your query.

Comment: @nl-x - or even better - use PDO :-)

Comment: @user1583647 please update your question to reflect your changes. and if db.php isn't too bid, paste it as well.

Comment: does your query returns back any result in `mysql console` or `phpmyadmin`? just echo your query in `php` and copy & paste and run it manually in `mysql` to see if it's working at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're dealing with so many files I would try another approach. That would be to store all paths into an array, make a single query and associate id's with path's. I'm not sure this code will work (I haven't tested it), but I hope you get the picture:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if ($handle = opendir('C:\Users\adithi.a\Desktop\db_features')) {

//Store all paths into $image_paths array
$image_paths = array();
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    $entry=substr($entry,11,-4); //this seperates the file name db_feature_T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521.txt to T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521
    if (strlen($entry) !== 0) {
    $image_paths[]='dressimages/'.$entry.'.jpg';//I want to pass the img_path as it is saved in the database in the form of dressimages/T1..iOXXdrXXcAMEra_092521}
    }
}
closedir($handle);

//Implode paths
$pathQuotesArray = array_map('apply_quotes', $image_paths); //Looks like 'filename1', 'filename2' etc
$pathQuotes = implode(',', $pathQuotesArray); 

//Do one query 
$result=  mysql_query("select img_id from tbl_image WHERE img_path IN ($pathQuotes)") or die(mysql_error());

//Associate id's with paths
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $key[$data["img_id"]] = $data["img_path"];
}

echo $key[5]; //If img_id is 5, then it would show correct path (hopefully :-))

function apply_quotes($item)
{
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($item) . "'";
}



?>
```

Comment: yes it does when I comment the sql part but if the sql query in uncommented it agains goes to an infinite loop

Comment: the output is select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='dressimages/T1..aJXiRiXXborqo7_063510.jpg'
select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='dressimages/T1..aQXm0bXXboCaMY_025420.jpg'

Comment: and when I tied this              $sql = "select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='$image_path'";
     echo $sql . '<br />';
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                
                print_r($data);
                }
    } It again went to an infinite loop I dont know what is the problem

Comment: hm maybe the dots are causing an issue? Dots are used in regexp in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html. If you try to change name of files (so they are without dots: What happens)? Try to change filenames to: T1aQXm0bXXboCaMY_025420.jpg and T1aJXiRiXXborqo7_063510.jpg'

Comment: actually I have 30,000 images which has its corresponding text file. i am doing this to save it in the database so I dont think I can change the filename.

Comment: aha. are you really sure it's going into an infinite loop then??? 30.000 images with querying each image could take a lot of time...

Comment: but when i query the same thing in phpmyadmin it doesn't take so much time. I tired ginig a specific image url too  from php but no luck

Comment: The issue is that in the PHP code you're doing 30.000 queries. My guess is that you're not doing this in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Got this error----array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in C:\wamp\www\FashionBonanza\Readfile.php on line 28

Comment: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28006/discussion-between-user1583647-and-bestprogrammerintheworld)

Answer (score 4):

You have to first `fetch` the data from your result

```
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  // this is missing
print_r($data); // or 
echo $data["img_id"];
```

and in case there can be multiple results you can do so in a loop

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
print_r($data); // or 
echo $data["img_id"];
}
```

Comment: I tried this too. It doesn't work. The page is loading as it has gone in some infinite loop.

Comment: @user1583647 - I can assure you it has nothing to do with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result=  mysql_query("select img_id from tbl_image where img_path="$image_path) or die("Sorry");
```

Comment: Your way of assumption its wrong. PHP doesn't parse code without `quotes` inside the `mysql_query()`

Comment: isn't there at least a point missing to concat the query and the variable? And the single quotes are required, because the path is string, I guess - and it will break the query, especially if there are spaces in the variable ...?

Comment: u should have to echo query and then direct run to database

Comment: sorry I didn't get you.can you give an example

Comment: echo $sql; then output of this query direct run in mysql

Answer (score -3):

Just two ideas:

```
$result=  mysql_query("select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='".$image_path."'") or die("Sorry");
```

Maybe it's better to do it this way. Otherwise set a extra string variable for the SQL-query, so you can track the exact query, which was executed.

```
$sQry = "select img_id from tbl_image where img_path='".$image_path."'";
var_dump($sQry);
$result=  mysql_query($sQry) or die("Sorry");
```

So you can check, if the variable contains the correct value or not.

Next point is the "echo". You can't echo a result set, use functions like mysql-fetch-array() or mysql_fetch_assoc() - http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php - or other ones.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["img_id "];
}
```

Comment: I tried this too no result when I comment the sql part and echo the image_path it does but when I uncomment it it goes to an infinite loop i.e. the page keeps on loading